# How to replace a character within a matched pattern using ampersand (&)

Tags: sed, match, ampersand

When we match a pattern using sed, the matched pattern is stored in the "ampersand" (&) variable. IS there a way to replace a character in this matched pattern using the ampersand itself ?

For example, if & contains the string "apple1", how can I use & to make the string to "apple2" (i.e replace 1 by 2) ?

Comment: This isn't the way you use `&`. It might help if you explained why you wanted to do this.

Answer (score 26):

If I guessed right, what you want to do is to apply a subsitution in a pattern matched. You can't do that using `&`. You want to do this instead:

```
echo apple1 apple3 apple1 apple2 botemo1 | sed '/apple./ { s/apple1/apple2/g; }'
```

This means that you want to execute the command substitution only on the lines that matches the pattern `/apple./`.

Comment: Please explain to a longtime sed newbie like me why this is any better than `sed 's/apple1/apple2/g'`. Because I want to use `sed '/apple./ { s/1/2/g; }' ` and it changes it to `botemo2` which is totally counterintuitive.

Comment: @StevenLu Thing is sed is line-oriented, so `/apple./` means: apply the commands to follow only to the lines that match the pattern. Since `botemo1` is in the same line, sed will apply the substitution for it too.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use a capture group. A capture is used to grab a part of the match and save it into an auxiliary variable, that is named numerically in the order that the capture appears.

```
echo apple1 | sed -e 's/\(a\)\(p*\)\(le\)1/\1\2\32/g'
```

We used three captures:

1. The first one, stored in `\1`, contains an "a"
2. The second one, stored in `\2`, contains a sequence of "p"s (in the example it contains "pp")
3. The third one, stored in `\3`, contains the sequence "le"

Now we can print the replacement using the matches we captured: `\1\2\32`. Notice that we are using 3 capture values to generate "apple" and then we append a 2. This wont be interpreted as variable `\32` because we can only have a total of 9 captures.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: yes, but this doesn't handle multiple matches in a single line.

Comment: The backreferences are designed for referring to "stored matches" (as the OP phrased); and the question is about replacing a string IN those, not WITH those.

Comment: Adding an example to 7heo.tk's comment. You can use back references like so: `sed -e 's/\(a\)\(p*\)\(le\)1 \1\2\32/\1\2\33 \1\2\34/'` will replace `apple1 apple2` with  `apple3 apple4`, and it would also work (if you want to) with `appple1 appple2`, resulting in `appple3 appple4`. However, it wouldn't replace `apple1 aple2`, nor `appple1 apple2`, nor `apple1 appple2`, because they don't have the same string stored in the captures (ie. when comparing the words, they're not the same).

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho I didn't know that you can use the backreferences in the match part of the regex. Do you know if it's POSIX?

Comment: @7heo.tk Yes, AFAICT, it's part of BRE (basic regular expressions) that every POSIX capable sed should implement (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06).

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho I have tested that against GNU and BSD implementations, I have found that in both cases, `sed 's/\(["'"'"']\)\(.*\)\1/\2/g'` actually yields the string between quotes, be them single quotes or double quotes. That's very useful, I'll surely keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I like what you did there to match quoted strings. I'll also keep that trick in mind :-)

Answer (score 13):

you can first match a pattern and then change the text if matched:

```
echo "apple1" | sed '/apple/s/1/2/'    # gives you "apple2"
```

this code changes `1` to `2` in all lines containing `apple`

Comment: Thanks! I feel I understand `sed` better after reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
sed 's/apple1/sed "s|1|2|" <<<"&"/e' file
```

Comment: OK, worked it out... Normally the "replacement" string is inserted, but GNU sed uses the `e` flag to execute it and insert its output instead.  The executed command passes `&` (the matched pattern) as a here-string to `sed "s|1|2"`, where `|` takes the place of the more conventional `/`.