# Stripped first X characters from string in shellscript using SED and now store as variable?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I know this is very similar to the question [How can I strip first X characters from string using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469989/how-can-i-strip-first-x-characters-from-string-in-shellscript-using-sed)

But I am having trouble storing the output string as a variable in my bash script

```
myString='Foo: 1234'
echo "$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//'
```

produces the desired result yet it is not stored in variable.... when i try:

```
myVariable1=$('"$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//'')
myVariable2='"$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//''
myVariable3=$(""$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//'")
myVariable4=""$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//'"
```

anyone care to show me where I'm going wrong please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep the `echo`:

```
myVar=$(echo "$myString"| sed -r 's/^.{5}//')
```

or use a here-string:

```
myVar=$(sed -r 's/^.{5}//' <<<"$myString")
```

Comment: wonderful I did not know you could pass the echo, problem solved :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need sed for this. bash can do it.

```
$ myString='Foo: 1234'
$ myVar=${myString:5}
$ echo $myVar
1234
```

Comment: yes i can confirm that this worked on the example you show thank you, yet when I try on my actual string it does not!! is there special characters i need to watch out for this way?? my string is:  'block.GetHash = 21f909a7d7efb8c7b0f6bee1f518bf1bbb7651b999b8e7cd6a2edc8f785b65a5'

Comment: $ test='block.GetHash = 21f909a7d7efb8c7b0f6bee1f518bf1bbb7651b999b8e7cd6a2edc8f785b65a5'
----
$ echo ${test:5}
.GetHash = 21f909a7d7efb8c7b0f6bee1f518bf1bbb7651b999b8e7cd6a2edc8f785b65a5