# Remove 4 chars before the last char with sed (or awk)

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to remove the 4 chars before the last char.

**Input**:

```
abc2a982
e1kei9e5bc5
e1edeaww58476
```

**Expected output**:

```
abc2
e1kei95
e1edeaww6
```

So far I have tried:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/.\{4}$\1/';done
```

I guess there should be something else instead of `\1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I strip first X characters from string using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469989/how-can-i-strip-first-x-characters-from-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% cat input | sed 's/....\(.\)$/\1/'
abc2
e1kei95
e1edeaww6
```

Comment: LOL, unless "cat input" is a placeholder for a much more complicated pipeline.

Comment: Actually I tried this solution, but my error was that I put '\\(.\\)' for all '.' but the first.

Comment: @achille - that wasn't included in your question, but it should still work. You could just count the parenthesized expressions, and select the one you want to place in your replacement string.  `'s/....\(.\)$/\1/'` is functionally equivalent to `'s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)$/\5/'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the urge to do this with bash alone, and avoid using sed, you could use [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to manipulate your strings.

```
while read -r line; do
  allbutlast1="${line%?}"          # strip the last character from $line
  lastchar="${line#$allbutlast1}"  # strip what we just captured from start of line
  allbutlast5="${line%?????}"      # strip the last 5 characters
  printf '%s%s\n' "$allbutlast5" "$lastchar"
done
```

Or if you're using bash as your shell, you have [additional options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s%s\n' "${line:0:$(( ${#line} - 5))}" "${line:$(( ${#line} - 1 ))}"
done
```

<sup>(bash code compacted to save on throw-away variables.)</sup>

The POSIX code (first example) uses parameter expansions `${var%...}` and `${var#...}` to construct the output. The Bash code uses `${var:start:length}` notation, with [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html), `$(( ... ))`.

This answer is included mostly for academic purposes. You'll get better performance using awk or sed than processing input line by line with a shell script.

Speaking of which, an awk solution might mirror the bash solution:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-5) substr($0,length($0))}'
```

Note that while bash's `${var:start:length}` notation starts numbering characters at zero, awk's `substr()` function starts at one.

Comment: Bash 4.3 or newer can do `printf '%s%s\n' "${line:0:-5}" "${line:(-1)}"`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that. :)